# Unique Records Based On Employee Name

Tags: sql, count, unique, multiple-columns

Greetings to everyone :)

There is a scenario where an employee is considered active with the company based on whether they are active with at least one of the company's clients. The example below illustrates this. All six records belong to the same employee, EmpX, shown under the Full_Name column. However, because EmpX provides services to six clients, C1, C2, etc., as shown in the column Code, EmpX appears 6 times with different Start dates (always has a value) and End_Date (which will have a value only if EmpX service to this client has been discontinued.)

What I'm trying to do is to count the number of employees who have been active in each year. The active criterion is that if the employee has been active for at least one client during that year (the start date is equal to or less than the year) then this employee gets counted as active in, say 2020. I managed to do this step by adding the last three columns indicating if the employee was/is active during that year for that client. However, I now need to count the employees that were/are active under each year. If I add the 1s under each of the columns, I will clearly count the same employee multiple times as being active during this year.

In the below example, EmpX should be counted as only 1 under each year, rather than now 5 under 2020, 4 under 2021 and 4 under 2022.

In summary, I need to count the employee as being active for our company (not the client) during a given year. The employee is active for the company if they are active with at least one client. Once that is accomplished, I can then sum up the number of active employees per year in order to produce the total per year of active employees for our company.

Thank you.

| code | FULL_NAME | Start_Date | End_Date | ACTIVE_2020 | ACTIVE_2021 | ACTIVE_2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | EmpX | 2017-04-21 | NULL | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| c2 | EmpX | 2014-12-24 | 2021-05-12 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| c3 | EmpX | 2013-01-11 | NULL | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| c4 | EmpX | 2013-05-31 | NULL | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| c5 | EmpX | 2014-12-24 | NULL | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| c6 | EmpX | 2017-04-21 | 2017-04-21 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: which rdms are you using?

Comment: and what have you attempted?

Comment: @nbk thanks. I’m using SQL server and ssms.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Thanks. I added the last three columns. I couldn’t figure out the rest. I thought of using unpivot, but I am foggy about it and also I don’t have experience using it.

Comment: this looks more like you should generate a series of dates between start and end  and then check with a case when. a simple pivot alone isn't enough

Comment: @nbk Thanks. It stumped me; that's why I resorted to this forum.